# select generated auto increment value from an inserted row

Tags: mysql

I want to insert a new line into a table in my database, the inserted line has an auto increment primary key, I want to select this generated value to use it in another table.

Here is my script :

```
INSERT INTO Inventaire(`date`) VALUES (DATE(NOW());
INSERT INTO LigneInterventaire(codeArt, qteInv, numInv) 
VALUES (NEW.codeArt, NEW.qte, <`Here I want that value`>);
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function is for:

```
INSERT INTO LigneInterventaire(codeArt, qteInv, numInv) 
VALUES (NEW.codeArt, NEW.qte, LAST_INSERT_ID());
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use LAST_INSERT_ID()

You can use this directly in your MYSQL code

ex:

```
INSERT INTO Inventaire(`date`) VALUES (DATE(NOW());

SET @the_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO LigneInterventaire(codeArt, qteInv, numInv) 
VALUES (NEW.codeArt, NEW.qte, @the_id);
```